# SQL: Return only the most recent activity per customer

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have two tables with linked data. There are activity updates against individual customers (customer_id). I want to return the most recent activity per customer;

**contact**;
customer_id  (auto_increment)
last_name 
first_name
phone_work

**activity**;
activity_id (auto_increment)
data_item_id
entered_by
date_created
notes

I can return the entire set of activities;

SELECT last_name, first_name, date_created, notes, FROM contact JOIN activity ON contact.customer_id=activity.data_item_id;

..but I only want the most recent activity per customer_name. If I use unique, it seems to return the first activity per customer_name and not the most recent. I'm sure it's extrememly simple but I've not found it yet. Thoughts?

Comment: Just a guess... try adding another column: `SELECT MAX(entered_by date_created), last_name, ...`. That should pick the correct row from the second table.

Comment: Thanks marki, worked on it some more, that looks good of course (!) using max (date_created);
SELECT  last_name, first_name, max(date_created) AS date, notes, FROM contact JOIN activity ON contact.customer_id=activity.data_item_id ORDER BY customer_id ASC;

Comment: You'll want to confirm that the `note` column is from the same row (most recent activity) - this looks a little strange to me using MAX() without a GROUP BY...

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-row.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(date_created)` to choose the correct row from the joined table. Otherwise MySQL would join all the rows, or in case of `GROUP BY`, choose the first matching row it finds.

So the query would be:

```
SELECT MAX(date_created) AS date, last_name, first_name, notes
       FROM contact JOIN activity ON contact.customer_id=activity.data_item_id
       ORDER BY customer_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

> `WITH TempTbl AS (
>   SELECT 
>      MAX(activity_id) activity_id --as it is auto_increment, this should return the most recent record)
>     ,Last_Name
>     ,First_Name
>     ,Date_Created
>     ,Notes
>   FROM Activity
>   JOIN Contact ON Contact.Customer_Id=Activity.Data_Item_Id
>   )
>   SELECT * FROM TempTbl`

if you still have multipe records per customer, then suggestion will be to consider using RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY... to select most recent record

Answer (score 0):

One more solution :

```
 select temp.* from
 ( 
  SELECT c.last_name last, c.first_name first, a.date_created, a.notes 
  FROM contact c JOIN activity a ON c.customer_id=a.data_item_id
  order by a.date_created desc
 ) temp
 group by temp.last, temp.first;
```